# delete record from database without refreshing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have an code where it is supposed to delete the data without refreshing. the delete process works but i have to refresh to to remove the data. 
heres my code please help me

Ajax:

```
$(function () {
  $(".trash").click(function () {
    var del_id = $(this).attr("id");
    var info = 'id=' + del_id;
    if (confirm("Sure you want to delete this post? This cannot be undone later.")) {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "delete.php", //URL to the delete php script
        data: info,
        success: function () {}
      });
      $(this).parents(".record").animate("fast").animate({
        opacity: "hide"
      }, "slow");
    }
    return false;
  });
});
```

Here's my html:

```
<td style="padding-left: 23px">
    <img class="photo" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#gallery<?php echo $photo; ?>"  src="<?php echo $r1['photo'];  ?>" />

    <div class="hotel">
        <button class="trash" id="<?php echo $r1['photo_id']; ?>" > <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
    </div>
</td>
```

If I hover the button to the image the `.trash` button will appear and if I click it the image must be deleted. help me please.

Comment: what is in your browser console?

Comment: im a newbie in ajax so i dont know how bind works

Comment: The code shown references a class `.record`, but no elements in the HTML shown have that class. When you say "without refreshing", do you mean that you do want that item to be removed from the page, but without reloading the whole page?

Comment: yeah. the i code i had deletes the record but i can still see it in my page once i refresh the page it disappears.

Comment: @AnecitoAlimaSantillan — https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/bcrfLjud/1/

Comment: what u r getting in info is right?

Comment: @Rayon it still wont work i still have to refresh the page just so the image disappears

Comment: @AnecitoAlimaSantillan — `Image` ? Where it is located ?

Comment: @Anju yeah its the id of the photo in the database

Comment: @Rayon its the image that i want to remove. i have table with images from the database. if i hover the image  the .trash button will appear

Comment: @AnecitoAlimaSantillan — IMO, It is more of a DOM structure related issue.. Do share a executable demo/snippet or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ? [_Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example_](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Rayon it has been solved already, thanks.

Comment: @AnecitoAlimaSantillan If you call the php(for print the image from database) direct from html .I think you should use ajax script for call to print the image from database via php.And applied result of ajax in your html page.The will be printed.And give some set interval function of the ajax script `setInterval{ajax(php),10}` it will  be with 10ms second.so when the image was deleted.the image will be automatically disapper.Its depend on your database record's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give a data image id attr to parent tr,

```
<tr data-image-id="<?php echo $r1['photo_id']; ?>">
```

After successful delete process (in your ajax success function) you can run code below.

```
$("tr[data-image-id="+del_id+"]").remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works, maybe  do you need show the complete html, or at least the classes ".record" to analyze the "error"

Answer (score 0):

No need to add extra attribute for ID in table row(TR).

```
$('.glyphicon-remove').on('click',function() { 
  $(this).closest( 'tr').remove();
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```js
function delete_value(id)
    {
      if(confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this?'))
      {
        // ajax delete data from database
          $.ajax({
            url : "<?php echo site_url('yoururl/del')?>/"+id,
            type: "POST",
            success: function(data)
            {
          $("tr[id="+id+"]").remove();
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
            {
                alert('Error deleting data');
            }
        });

      }
    }
```

```html
<button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="delete_value(<?php echo $row->id;?>)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></button>

<!--- add tr id --->
<tr id="<?php echo $row->id; ?>">
```